# Unresolved Reference "widget_tweaks"

Tags: python, django

I am quite new to Django.
I have installed the django-widget-tweaks in my project.
And I have also included "widget_tweaks" in the INSTALLED_APPS.
However, pycharm shows the unresolved reference error of "widget_tweaks".
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thank you!

the INSTALLED_APPS looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
'south',
'widget_tweaks',
'main_app',
```

)

and the 'widget_tweaks' is highlighted as "unresolved reference"

Comment: Can you show the code that references `widget_tweaks`?

Comment: the reference is just under INSTALLED_APPS:

Comment: Can you show the code and the exception? Also what did you do to install the package?

Comment: Hi, I installed it using pip.

Comment: it turns out that I need to use the Pycharm IDE to install it...